# How to use videojs-contextmenu in a custom Videojs component?

Tags: video.js

I have built a custom video player component in React using video js. I am trying to implement a context menu using videojs-contextmenu and videojs-contextmenu-ui. However when I try to initialize the plugin, I get the following error.

```
Message: Uncaught TypeError: this.playerInstance.contextmenuUI is not a function - URL: webpack-internal:///375 - Line: 116 - Column: 27 - Error object: {}
```

Since I have customised the components, how do I initialize the plugin. I have imported videojs and only after that have I imported videojs-contextmenu and videojs-contextmenu-ui.

```
import videojs from 'video.js';
import SmartModeToggleMenuButton from './SmartModeToggleMenuButton';
import 'videojs-contextmenu';
import 'videojs-contextmenu-ui';

const Player = videojs.getComponent('Player');
videojs.registerComponent('smartModeToggleMenuButton', SmartModeToggleMenuButton);

class SmartModePlayer extends Player {

  constructor(tag, options,ready) {
    super(tag,options, ready);
    //some custom code
  }      

}

videojs.registerComponent('SmartModePlayer', SmartModePlayer);

export default SmartModePlayer;
```

Then, elsewhere I use the SmartModepLayer as follows:

```
this.playerInstance = new SmartModePlayer(this.kaalRecordingPlayer, options , function () {});
this.playerInstance.contextmenuUI();
```

How do I correctly use videojs-conetxtmenu-ui plugin when using in a custom component as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to specifically call these 2 lines:

```
videojs.registerPlugin('contextmenu', VjsContextMenu);
videojs.registerPlugin('contextmenuUI', VjsContextMenuUI);
```